# How to invoke the JavaScript function from code behind (c# / controller)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC, Controller - I will have to enable or disable the text box in the page load event.

Mentioned line of syntax is written inside a JS file / function.

```
document.getElementById('ShowTextBox').disabled = false;
```

How to invoke the JavaScript function from code behind (c# / controller)?

Comment: what you mean "in c# code" ? can you be more specific with relevant code ?

Comment: Just call that syntax from .net code. There is a syntax -ScriptManager .. i forgot that syntax

Comment: Sorry! Still not following what you are trying to do. You forgot what syntax ?

Comment: @shyju , I am sorry.  There is way to invoke Javascript function from code behind.

Comment: What you mean code behind ? If you meant controller code, it is executed on server. JavaScript gets executed on client browser.

Comment: Unless you clarify your question, it seems using `ViewBag` for use in your `view` (for any client side code to use) is what you're looking for (or XHR/Ajax for more).

Comment: JavaScript is executed in the browser, so you'll need to put this code in a static JavaScript file.

Comment: I meant to say Code Behind as Controller. I will have to invoke a JS function from Controller

Comment: I already have the JS function  in a JS file. I just want to invoke the file / function from Controller

Comment: You can't invoke client-side JavaScript functions from your server. You'll need to write JavaScript that will invoke the function as needed. If you want the textbox to be disabled during rendering, then you simply add the `disabled` attribute to your html tag.

Comment: @TLP , Text box has to be disabled based on condition.  Not all the Text box can be disabled. If certain condition is true, enable the text box. If not , keep the text box disable

Comment: If you want to do this during rendering, you'll need to write server-side code to achieve this (not JavaScript). If you want to do this on the client, then you'll need to write JavaScript. It's hard to give a more specific answer without knowing how your project is organized.

Answer (score 1):

Arg, too many comments:

- if you have a simple need to send some result of server side processing to your `View`, one time (onload), then you have `ViewBag` and/or `ViewData`
- Ajax/XHR for more processing
- even partials if you ever have to (partial views with javascript mixed in with c# or vb stuff)

---

> `<textarea id="ShowTextBox" asp-for="ShowTextBox" style="height:150px;" class="form-control"></textarea>`

Trivial sample only improve as needed:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //some server side processing....
    ViewBag.Foo = DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0;
    return View();
}
```

View (`index.cshtml`):

```
<textarea id="ShowTextBox" asp-for="ShowTextBox" style="height:150px;" class="form-control"></textarea>


<script>
    // trivial example only 
    document.getElementById('ShowTextBox').disabled = @ViewBag.Foo;
</script>
```

REF:
[Passing data to views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1#passing-data-to-views) - doc is for `Core`, but same concept.

Comment: Thank you @EdSF,  considering this control name : ShowTextBox  which is defined on <Textbox> attribute in client side, How will i get this element id inside the viewbag?

Comment: @goofyui Wait, what do you mean by `control` in the context of `MVC`? `controls` are for `WebForms`.

Comment: <textarea id="ShowTextBox" asp-for="ShowTextBox" style="height:150px;" class="form-control"></textarea>            --- "ShowTextBox is the name of my HTML TextBox control. I will have to fetch that element id in the controller.cs ; In which i  will have to enable or disable based on conditional result populated from database

Comment: @goofyui a **trivial** example is above. You can "pass" data to the `view` from the controller in many different ways. At the `view`, that data can be rendered "anywhere" and used for anything on the client side. Hth.

Comment: as always ... very helpful.  Now .. where you are writing this syntax : <script>
    // trivial example only 
    document.getElementById('ShowTextBox').disabled = @ViewBag.Foo;
</script>   -- This is on .cshtml page ??

Comment: Thanks .. helpful

Comment: @goofyui updated the answer - `cshtml` (`vbhtml` for VB.Net) are the (Razor) `Views` in ASP.Net MVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179685/discussion-between-goofyui-and-edsf).